# How do you store the results of a Query in an Application variable in WebMatrix?

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I have a .cs file in my App_Code folder that is doing this:

```
dynamic HomePageFeaturedItems=db.Query("dbo.homepage_featured_items");
HttpContext.Current.Application["FeaturedItems"]=HomePageFeaturedItems;
```

I'd like to iterate over the results in my .cshtml like this:

```
@foreach(dynamic item in HttpContext.Current.Application["FeaturedItems"]){
        <li>
            <a href="/auctions/@(item.itemTitle)">@item.itemTitle</a>
        </li>
    }
```

But it obviously doesn't have an enumerator.  I've been trying to wrap my head around how WebMatrix returns results...

Should I be storing it in the application variable in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing objects and making Lists of them, and then placing that in the Application variable...not really the dynamic magic I think they intended but it works.

Comment: That is the way I would do it too.